# Why can't I display multiple graphs in one HTML page using D3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Title. I'm a noob at this, and this has been frustrating me for 2 days now. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. D3 is frustrating....

I'm trying to create multiple graphs in one page. For now, only 1 bar graph displays. I have different divs each with their own unique ID's, so not sure what's going wrong here.  In addition to that, for some strange reason I can't add any text to the bars in the bargraphs I'm trying to create.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
TESTING

<body>
<div id="chart1" style = "position:static; left: 420px; bottom: 10px; float:left">                                            
    <h4>Positivity</h4>
    <script>
        const dataset1 = [32, 45, 22, 26, 23, 18, 29, 14, 9];

        const w = 500;
        const h = 100;

        const chart1 = d3.select("#chart1")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        chart1.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset1)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => h - 3 * d)
        .attr("width", 25)
        .attr("height", (d, i) => 3 * d)
        .attr("fill", "navy");

        chart1.selectAll("text")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", (d,i)=>i*30)
        .attr("y", (d,i)=>{return (h-(d*3)-3);})
        .text(function (d){return d;});
    </script>
   
</div>

<div id="chart2" style = "position:relative; left: 50px; bottom:0px; float:center">                                            
    <h4>Motivation</h4>
    <script>
        const dataset2 = [12, 31, 22, 17, 25, 18, 29, 14, 9];

        const w = 500;
        const h = 100;

        const svg2 = d3.select("#chart2")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        svg2.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset2)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => h - 3 * d)
        .attr("width", 25)
        .attr("height", (d, i) => 3 * d)
        .attr("fill", "navy");

        svg2.selectAll("text")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        // Add your code below this line
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", (d,i)=>i*30)
        .attr("y", (d,i)=>{return (h-(d*3)-3);})
        .text(function (d){return d;});

        // Add your code above this line
    </script>
   
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the question title; instead mark one of the answers as the "correct" one below

Answer (score 1):

For your second bar chart you're selecting the wrong chart div.

Change this

`d3.select("#chart1")`

to

`d3.select("#chart2")`

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! That was part of the solution haha. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things

Change

```
const svg2 = d3.select("#chart1")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", w)
              .attr("height", h);
```

to say `d3.select("#chart2")` ect.

Number 2, is that you define `w` and `h` twice, which causes errors because  you used `const`.

Number 3

```
selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
```

should use `dataset1` and `dataset2`.

I will say that these errors (mostly) can be determined by looking at the errors in the console

Comment: You are not stupid,  these things can happen to everyone